# How to separate with comma values fetched by loop from mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am creating a web application which requires a kind of series of related data from database, and those data should be separated by commas,

For hint : I am fetching those values with while loop

```
<?php while ( $writer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqi8)) { ?>
<?=$writer['fullname']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

So in the code above there more than one names from the database and i want to separate them with comma when they are fetched

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to use the implode() command in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: imploade(",",$writer['fullname']);

Comment: @SachinAghera `imploade` is not a function :)

Comment: implode(",",$writer['fullname']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner way to achieve that would be this:

```
<?php
    $fullNames = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqi8)) {
        $fullNames[] = $row["fullname"];
    }

    foreach ($fullNames as $fullName) { ?>
       <a href="cast-profile.php?cast=<?=$fullName;?>"><?=$fullName; ?> </a>,  
<?php
    } 
?>
```

Comment: thanks but how can i use these codes in kind of following codes

Comment: Writer:  <?php while ( $writer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqi8)) { ?>
                              <a  href = "cast-profile.php?cast=<?=$writer['person'];?>"><?=$writer['person']?></a> 
                              <?php }?>

Comment: Do you want to use the `fullname` or `person` or both?

Comment: fullname and person is the same i just wrote fullname so that you can get the picture of what i really need to fetch

Comment: vut sorry how can i make those names a link

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Not formatted properly I had to type on cellphone.

Comment: Yes I forgot while updating the first time. I re updated the code and it should work now. I guess one shouldn't post answers by typing in cellphones :)